# Using values from Temp table in Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a temp table which has few records . I need to include them in my Dynamic SQL.I am trying to do something like this

```
SET @SQL=@SQL + 'Select '+ @fields + ' ID from dbo.EmployeePension()' 
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE EmployeeID IN'
SET @SQL= @SQL + '(Select EmployeeID from' + #temp4 + ')'
EXEC @SQL
```

where #temp4 is my temporary table.
I am actually pulling @fields from a separate table and then retrieving the same columns from the function.

Can someone help me on how to include the temp table values in dynamic SQL.
I am expecting a dynamic SQL like

Select name,age,sex from dbo.EmployeePension() where EmployeeID IN(Select EmployeeID in (100,101,102));

where (100,101,102) are values in temp table and name,age,sex are values in @fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'Select '+ @fields + ' ID from dbo.EmployeePension()' 
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE EmployeeID IN'
SET @SQL = @SQL + '(Select EmployeeID from #temp4)'
EXEC ( @SQL )
```